# maximum number of edges in graph using

Tags: optimization, graph, graph-theory

How can I find the maximum number of edges from a graph using only a limited number of nodes say N nodes. A selected edge uses both sides of it.

Comment: "A selected edge uses both sides of it." Both sides of what?

Comment: Are you talking about graph matching?

Comment: `n(n-1)/2` is that what you asked for?

Comment: An edge uses both sides of itself. Also the graph is not complete. The context of problem may help. I have lots of pairs of IPs but can only select 100 unique IPs. Now want to cover the most number of IP pairs in the system. An IP pair will be covered if both IPs are in the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A known problem.** Sounds as though your problem is known as [k-densest subgraph problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_subgraph) (your N playing the role of k).

**Bad news**: This problem is known to be NP-hard, [even if none of your IPs occur more than three times](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.37.9962) or the input graph is bipartite. Are you aware of any other special properties of your graph?

**More bad news**: From a quick look around the recent literature, it looks as though not even algorithms with good error bounds are readily available. To my mind, the problem could be nasty even with "only" 100 input nodes.

Best of luck!